# React functional component not returning result without generic HTML tag

Tags: reactjs

I am on path of learning React and I was practicing functional components.

I saw an example where a functional component was returning the result without a return keyword. I did not see what the parent tag was in that example, and I tried to practice it by myself on my local.

After writing and running the code I did not get any output on the browser, instead an error was thrown saying that there should be a parent tag to enclose the other mentioned components.

I did not understand why such error was thrown, although I have used a parent tag to enclose other code inside it. That parent tag was not a generic HTML tag, instead it was a custom component tag. I then tried with a parent tag of HTML  and the result was returned on the browser.

I am not able to understand the reason behind such behaviour of React and why React does not support custom component tag as a parent tag. Please help.

For reference my code had a structure as given below:

**WITHOUT GENERIC HTML TAG:-**

```
export const Parent = () => {
     <SmallModal
            className='parent-modal'
            isOpen={true}
        >
            <BodyGrey>
                <header className='equip-modal-header'>
                    Practising React
                </header>
                <div>
                    <p>This is a functional component without return keyword.</p>
                </div>                
            </BodyGrey>
        </SmallModal>
}
```

**WITH GENERIC HTML TAG:-**

```
export const Parent = () => {
<div>
     <SmallModal
            className='parent-modal'
            isOpen={true}
        >
            <BodyGrey>
                <header className='equip-modal-header'>
                    Practising React
                </header>
                <div>
                    <p>This is a functional component without return keyword.</p>
                </div>                
            </BodyGrey>
        </SmallModal>
</div>
}
```

Comment: just add return( ... ) to the first body line of Parent in both cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is about [`arrow functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), when you want to return value without the `return` keyword, the body of your function should be wrapped with `()` not `{}`, like this:

```
export const Parent = () => (
     <SmallModal
            className='parent-modal'
            isOpen={true}
        >
            <BodyGrey>
                <header className='equip-modal-header'>
                    Practising React
                </header>
                <div>
                    <p>This is a functional component without return keyword.</p>
                </div>                
            </BodyGrey>
        </SmallModal>
)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake in practicing React. I did the change suggested by you and it worked.